# DFS Provider Cache

Tags: windows, active-directory, dfs

My organization has multiple mapped drives that target DFS paths such as \\domain\HOME\HomeDrives\username. When trying to access one of the mapped drives after connecting to VPN, the following error occurs:

> An error occurred while reconnecting U: to
> \\domain\HOME\HomeDrives\username  Microsoft Windows Network: The
> network path was not found. This connection has not been restored.

The problem resolves itself by waiting up to 20 minutes or it can be resolved immediately by running the following command:

```
dfsutil cache Provider flush
```

Will someone please help me understand what the problem is and explain what the DFS provider cache is and how the cache lifetime can be reduced?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/change-the-amount-of-time-that-clients-cache-referrals

Comment: Thank you, @joeqwerty. I have seen this article and decreased both cache durations to 1 second with no change.